# duplicate files during packaging of APK: colors.xml

Tags: android

I'm attempting to build the project, and I see this error:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Android\Git\my_android_project\project\build\outputs\apk\project-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: values/colors.xml
    Origin 1: C:\Android\Git\my_android_project\project\build\intermediates\javaResources\debug\values\colors.xml
    Origin 2: C:\Android\Git\my_android_project\project\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\my_android_project\androidsupportv7appcompat\unspecified\jars\classes.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'values/colors.xml'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':project:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK values/colors.xml
    File 1: C:\Android\Git\my_android_project\project\build\intermediates\javaResources\debug\values\colors.xml
    File 2: C:\Android\Git\my_android_project\project\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\my_android_project\androidsupportv7appcompat\unspecified\jars\classes.jar
```

of course there's a couple of /res/values/colors.xml because of the support library and my own project... I thought they are supposed to be merged ?!

**Why aren't the colors.xml merged into the APK?**

**There's no duplicate values:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="button_background_rest">#CCFFFFFF</color>
     <color name="button_background_press">#CC00529C</color>
     <color name="loading_gray">#CC56595E</color>
     <color name="loading_bar_blue_20">#2079C7F7</color>
     <color name="loading_bar_blue_80">#8079C7F7</color>
     <color name="loading_bar_blue_100">#ff79C7F7</color>
     <color name="transparent">@android:color/transparent</color>
     <color name="skyblue">#79C7F7</color>
     <color name="gray">#6C6F73</color>
     <color name="semitransparent_gray">#806C6F73</color>
     <color name="blaze">#72C000</color>
     <color name="dusk">#F26A08</color>
     <color name="envy">#950A14</color>
     <color name="white">@android:color/white</color>
     <!-- color name="light_gray">#87898D</color -->
     <color name="dark_gray">#56595E</color>
     <color name="light_gray">#8C97A5</color>
     <color name="transparent_dark_gray">#B0000000</color>
     <color name="blue">#80D1F5</color>
     <color name="recent_gray">#B0888A8D</color>
     <color name="black">@android:color/black</color>
</resources>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<resources>
    <color name="abc_search_url_text_normal">#7fa87f</color>
    <color name="abc_search_url_text_selected">@android:color/black</color>
    <color name="abc_search_url_text_pressed">@android:color/black</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you using last version of appcompat library?

Comment: have you used jar for depedency ?

Comment: @Santiago, no, this appcompat is quite old

Comment: I have this error documented with a error in appcompat library, in my case I only update to last version for solve. This error was after update sdk tools to version 24

Comment: may be due to old version of gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around quite a bit, for example upgrading to appCompat 23.0.1 and compiling with compiler ver. 23

However, none of that stuff prevented the APK build failure.

What ultimately fixed it:

**1)** Android Studio, when I imported the project from Eclipse, created "res" and "resources" folders.

**2)** I went through all of the modules and deleted the "resources" folders !!

**3)** clean the project and rebuild.

What's the point of Android Studio creating the "resources" folders ?